# Async validator for unique userId not working

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

Inside service-

```
getUserIdToCheckDuplicate(userId:any):Observable<any>{
    const url = ``; //url goes here
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
  }
```

Inside component-

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      userId: ['', [Validators.required],[this.existingUserIdValidator()]]
    }

get userId() {
    return this.form.get("userId");
  }

existingUserIdValidator(initialID: string = ""): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (
      control: AbstractControl
    ):
      | Promise<{ [key: string]: any } | null>
      | Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
      if (control.value === initialID) {
        return of(null);
      } 
      else {
        return control.valueChanges.pipe(
          debounceTime(500),
          take(1),
          switchMap(_ =>
            this.userService
              .getUserIdToCheckDuplicate(control.value)
              .pipe(
                map(user =>
                  user ? { existingUserId: { value: control.value } } : null
                )
              )
          )
        );
      }
    };
  }
```

Inside html-

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="1 1 calc(25% - 10px)" fxFlex.lt-md="1 1 calc(25% - 10px)"fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" class="from-color">
    <mat-label class="label-padding">User ID</mat-label>
       <input class="label-padding" formControlName="userId" matInput placeholder="User ID" required />
          <div style="color: red; font-weight: bold;" *ngIf="userId.errors.existingUserId">Already Exists !</div>
 </mat-form-field>
```

When I start entering anything the input field, it shows **"Cannot read property 'existingUserId' of null"**.

I've already followed various different ways to perform this async validation. But in my case, those never worked! I don't know where I'm making the mistake! Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The type definition of `userId.errors` is `ValidationErrors | null`.
So if there is no error, you can't access the `existingUserId` property.

You can fix this way : `userId.errors?.existingUserId`.
It'll only try to access **existingUserId** if errors is not null.

About the validator itself, you can't get the validation on the expected value by using `valueChanges`.
Here is a solution :

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

existingUserIdValidator(initialID: string = ""): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (
      control: AbstractControl
    ):
      | Promise<{ [key: string]: any } | null>
      | Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
      if (control.value === initialID) {
        return of(null);
      } 
      else {
        return timer(500).pipe(
          switchMap(_ =>
            this.userService
              .getUserIdToCheckDuplicate(control.value)
          ),
          map(user => user ? { existingUserId: { value: control.value } } : null
          )
        );
      }
    };
  }
```

Here is a naive sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uv3bv6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The errors from the console are gone now.

But still it is not working properly; showing **"Already Exists"** message always

Comment: with `take(1)` it only retrieves the first value emitted by valueChanges. You need to remove it.

Comment: the error message is gone now! not working properly :(

Comment: the validator is called when the value changed but once inside, you are waiting for another change with valueChanges to evaluate the validation. So you don't evaluate the right data : by typing 123, then 4, the validation will be on 123. And if you don't type anything after 4, the validation won't be triggered on 1234

Comment: I see. Do you have any **solution** for this scenario? I want to type the user id & it will match with the backend data asynchronously. Before submitting the form I want to get the error message. Can you please help me out?

Comment: sorry, the last map operator must be on upper level.
I update the example with a stackblitz sample